# Typescript polymorphism of constructor

Tags: typescript, inheritance, constructor, polymorphism

Let's say we have this very simple architecture of classes :

```
class Vehicle {}

class Car extends Vehicle {
    wheels: Number

    constructor(wheels: Number) {
        super()
        this.wheels = wheels
    }
}
```

What I want is achieve to store in variable a constructor type that extends Vehicle, like this :

```
let vehicleConstructor: typeof Vehicle = Car  // this do not work
```

The compiler then complains that `Car` is not assignable to type `typeof Vehicle`. I can understand why : it's because the constructors of the two classes do not have the same signature. To create a car, the `wheels` parameter is mandatory, when a `Vehicle` needs no parameters.

What I actually want in my code is to have an array of Vehicle constructors :

```
let constructors: Array<typeof Vehicle> = [Car, Truck]
```

So that I can check if a random object is an instance of one of the elements in the array.

I won't use this array to create vehicles so I don't care about constructors' parameters. I only have to make sure I have an array of functions or class constructors *that return a `Vehicle`*, no matter the parameters.

Any idea about how I could achieve that? Is it only possible in Typescript?

Comment: For me your `let vehicleConstructor2: typeof Vehicle = Car` works fine without any complains.

Comment: Provide a full example. It should work, return values are covarinat,  if you have different parameters, then it might not work, but  then use a custom ctor signature `new () =>Vehicle` https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noImplicitReturns=false#code/MYGwhgzhAEBqCmALAlqe0DeBfAUKSMAwmAE7TwAeALvAHYAmMCKamuA9OwCqJ3QCS0YGFrQA9gCMAbsjEBXCCACe0emOgiVYgGbQqKGAHdk+6LXXAxAWwAOyEPDKOSYsgC4cOB1WhSkqBwBGNzh-VgBeM3hDUJYHL3gfPzj4ACYQ5gD0SNpo6GISHE4AITkfQWFaAHIfMGAUeD89dQgqV3RkUSlSZDAJBw0hMVpWkjlgNrIqJRt0fTAfShoGJjCHABpoEGQAazmDaA8EpLX4QmHR8cngvRn4HVis6EjM1mhOPQPDVx3j31PziMqGMJq50rdZg9XgNIgVoNAcEA

Comment: Works on my machine.

Comment: Indeed, I factorized the problem too much - until it actually works. I had an issue because in my code the constructors did not have the same signature. I'm updating the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, I found my answer thanks to **Titian Cernicova-Dragomir**'s tip.

What I needed to do is this :

```
let vehicleConstructor: (new(...args: any) => Vehicle) = Car
```